# MySql - Insert with IF and JOIN

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to add bonus points for users every 2 days. But I'm not sure how to join the `users` table and get the `user_bonus` value which indicates the last time a user received a bonus. Can this be done in one query?

Insert query:

```
INSERT INTO points_plus (user_id, points) VALUES (?,?);
```

This would be the 2 day interval which needs to be checked:

```
user_bonus <= NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY
```

users table(part of it)

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| weekly_mail | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| user_bonus  | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| join_date   | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

points_plus table

```
+----+---------+--------+---------------------+
| id | user_id | points | date                |
+----+---------+--------+---------------------+
| 18 |      13 |    300 | 2015-10-07 12:06:39 |
| 43 |      13 |     99 | 2015-10-18 14:16:50 |
| 45 |      13 |    103 | 2015-10-19 05:49:49 |
+----+---------+--------+---------------------+
```

Comment: please share your table structure

Comment: You have multiple entries for each user in `points_plus`? Why not update `points` column?

Comment: Yes. I have multiple entries for each user.

Comment: It is unclear what you are looking for. Can you include a full set of sample data along your expected result?

Comment: I want to insert a new row into points_plus, only if 2 days have passed since the last insert.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
INSERT INTO points_plus (user_id, points)
    SELECT id, $points
    FROM users
    WHERE user_bonus <= NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY
```